# Angular *ngFor approach for scoped flags set by mouseenter

Tags: angular, mouseenter, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I am switching from angular.js to angular2/4 and have trouble understanding how I should implement the following pattern ...

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (mouseenter)="focus=true" (mouseleave)="focus=false">

    <span>{{text}}</span>

    <i *ngIf="focus" class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>

</div>
```

In Angular.js a `focus` flag was created for each element iteration of the ng-for
but in Angular, the `focus` flag is global to all iterated div resulting in all pencil icons being displayed when the mouse enters a single div.

I am confused as to how I could replicate the old Angular.js functionality ?

*(I have "solved" this temporarily by using child components for each iteration, however, this seems like a hammer approach especially if the code is very small... where is the line drawn ?)*

Thanks 
Simon Price

Comment: Have you tried setting `item.focus` rather than just `focus`?

Comment: yes this  was my first approach, but it seemed dirty to be decorating data items with view flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the approach is overcomplicating the issue as there is a simpler option that doesn't involve javascript.

First add a couple of classes to the two elements that are involved (`parent` and `child` in this case, but anything that we can use later on to select them can be used):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" class="parent">
    <span>{{text}}</span>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil child" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Then you can use CSS to make the pencil appear/disappear depending on whether the mouse hovers the item.

```
.parent .child {
    display: none;
}

.parent:hover .child {
    display: inline;
}
```

This could be shortened to the following, depending on what kind of browsers need to be supported (see [this overview](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot)).

```
.parent:not(:hover) .child {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (mouseenter)="item.focus=true" (mouseleave)="item.focus=false">

    <span>{{text}}</span>

    <i *ngIf="item.focus" class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>

</div>
```

Comment: see comment above

Comment: Then how will you identify which div was focused if you use a single variable. You cant do that.